# Terraform - Error creating OpenStack loadbalancer: Resource not found

Tags: terraform, openstack, terraform-provider-openstack

I'm trying to create an OpenStack load balancer with Terraform but I get the following error upon `terraform apply`:

> Error: Error creating openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2: Resource not found
>
> on load-balancer/main.tf line 71, in resource
> "openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2" "lb_1":   71: resource
> "openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2" "lb_1" {

My template looks like the following.

```
resource "openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2" "lb_1" {
  name          = "loadbalancer"
  vip_subnet_id = openstack_networking_subnet_v2.public.id
}

resource "openstack_lb_listener_v2" "listener_1" {
  name                      = "https"
  protocol                  = "TERMINATED_HTTPS"
  protocol_port             = 443
  loadbalancer_id           = openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2.lb_1.id
  default_tls_container_ref = openstack_keymanager_container_v1.tls_1.container_ref
}

resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "lb_network" {
  name = "lb-network"
  port_security_enabled = "true"
}

resource "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "public" {
  name = "lb-subnet"
  network_id = openstack_networking_network_v2.lb_network.id
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
  ip_version = 4
}
```

I have no clue about how to debug further. Does it mean that `vip_subnet_id` isn't found? Or is `openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2` an unknown resource type?

I'm using Terraform v0.13.5 and terraform-provider-openstack v1.33.0.

**Update**

I created a LB manually via the web interface and now I tried to import it via Terraform CLI and got the following response

> Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
>
> While attempting to import an existing object to
> openstack_lb_loadbalancer_v2.lb_1, the provider detected that no
> object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be
> imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with
> the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply"
> to create a new remote object for this resource.

I start to suspect that this may be something wrong on the OpenStack server side.

Comment: I'm hitting the exact same issue with the terraform provider. So I think it's an issue with the terraform provider or OpenStack itself.

Comment: I've created a bug at here with terraform openstack: https://github.com/terraform-provider-openstack/terraform-provider-openstack/issues/1100

Comment: I checked the source code of the load balancer resource to figure out you have to set use_octavia if you're using octavia :) I posted an answer below. Hope that it will solve your issue too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out you need to set `use_octiva = true` in the openstack terraform provider settings. See relevant docs here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs#use_octavia

Example config:

```
cat main.tf
provider "openstack" {
  user_name     = var.os_user_name
  tenant_name   = var.os_tenant_name
  password      = var.os_password
  auth_url      = var.os_auth_url
  region        = var.os_region
  endpoint_type = var.os_endpoint_type
  use_octavia   = true
}
```

Here is the relevant bug report: https://github.com/terraform-provider-openstack/terraform-provider-openstack/issues/1100

Comment: This helped me , saved hell lot of time thank you so much.